# Stream collectingAndThen get latest record to sum a value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, groupingby

Currently, I'm facing with below dataset. My aim is to get the **latest** sum of Column4 group by the first two-column.

```
// Column5 = version
new Foo(1, "bbb", "cccc", 111, 0)
new Foo(1, "bbb", "cccc", 234, 1) // latest
new Foo(1, "bbb", "dddd", 111, 0)
new Foo(1, "bbb", "dddd", 112, 1)
new Foo(1, "bbb", "dddd", 113, 2)
new Foo(1, "bbb", "dddd", 114, 3) // latest
new Foo(1, "xxx", "cccc", 111, 0) // latest
new Foo(2, "xxx", "yyyy", 0, 0)
new Foo(2, "xxx", "yyyy", 1, 1)   // latest
...
```

What I have tried is

```
// key: Column1, key: Column2, value: latest sum of Column4
Map<Long, Map<String, Integer>> fooMap = fooList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getColumn1, Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getColumn2,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(????))));
```

whether the `????` part I've tried `Collectors.groupingBy`, `Collectors.maxBy`, `Collectors.summingInt`

but it is always wrong.

My ideal Map should be something like below:

`1->bbb->348`,`1->xxx->111`, `2->xxx->1`.

Please help  Let me know if any supplement wants to have. Thanks.

Comment: how did you choose `(1, "bbb", "dddd", 114, 3)` and `(1, "bbb", "cccc", 234, 1)`, both as latest? the third column also matters under grouping?

Comment: @Naman Yes. I want to get the sum of Column4 from latest record (Column5) group by Column 1 + 2 + 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with:

```
    Map<Long, Map<String, Integer>> fooMap = fooList.stream().collect(
            groupingBy(Foo::getColumn1,
                    groupingBy(Foo::getColumn2,
                            collectingAndThen(
                                    groupingBy(Foo::getColumn3,
                                            collectingAndThen(
                                                    maxBy(comparing(Foo::getVersion)),
                                                    Optional::get
                                            )),
                                    m -> m.values().stream().mapToInt(Foo::getColumn4).sum()
                            )
                    )
            ));
```

First group by column1 and column2, then we use a `collectingAndThen` for the grouping by column3, because we want to post process it.

Grouping by column3 we want to get the max by version, we use another `collectingAndThen`, because maxBy creates and `Optional`, so we apply an `Optional::Get` to get a `Map<String, Foo>` instead of a `Map<String, Optional<Foo>>`.

The post process is to sum all column4 of the Foo in the map, that are the ones with the max version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I only want to get the sum of Column4 from latest record (Column5) group by Column 1 + 2 + 3. 
e.g. `1->bbb->348` , which is from 234 + 114 from the dataset.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer

Comment: It should be what I want to have from the beginning 

Answer (score 2):

Representing models for simplification as:

```
record Foo(Long one, String two, String three, int value, int version) {
}

record Result(Long one, String two, int totalValue) {
}
```

You can start with grouping by the first three attributes and mapping the value to an identity choosing the maximum version.

```
Map<List<Object>, Foo> groupedMaxVersion = fooList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(foo -> Arrays.asList(foo.one(), foo.two(), foo.three()),
                foo -> foo, BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Foo::version))));
```

This could be followed by the summing downstream that you were looking for based on the value in column 4:

```
Map<List<Object>, Integer> resultMapping = groupedMaxVersion.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> Arrays.asList(e.getKey().get(0), e.getKey().get(1)),
                Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getValue().value())));
```

Further, you just need to frame it onto the result data structure as desired

```
resultMapping.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new Result((Long) e.getKey().get(0), (String) e.getKey().get(1), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```